# Confusion in Rails TimeZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, timezone, rails-activerecord

My  config for timezones looks like this

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
  config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

When I query for created_at of an Object it returns me a value like this

```
2.1.5 :070 > b.created_at
 => Tue, 07 Apr 2015 20:49:58 PDT -07:00
```

The DateTime value at the time of creation of the object was like this

```
2.1.5 :071 > DateTime.now
 => Wed, 08 Apr 2015 03:49:58 -0700
```

Which means the value I was getting for the created_at field was 7 hours behind PDT.I cannot understand why this happens.Is this because of any mistakes in my configs.

Comment: AR automatically converts datetime values to corresponding time zone which depends on your app config.

Comment: datetimes are stored in the database in UTC, ie "universal time", which is the same (for our purposes) as Greenwich Mean Time, ie "+0 time".  When they are displayed, they are converted into your local time zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, issue was in the

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

Postgresql saves the date in UTC and when we query it in rails it adjusts the timezones according to our configs.

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

the above line converts the times to PDT.

config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'

This line of config forces the app to save data in PDT timezone values to the DB,hence later when we query the console it again adjusts the time zone, hence there will be a 7 hours difference in the queried time.